# QGraphicsScene does not have a function to remove QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

QGraphicsScene has an `addWidget(QWidget *)` function, but no corresponding `removeWidget(QWidget *)`. It has only `removeItem(QGraphicsItem *)`.

How do I remove a QWidget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a basic sample, see if it works for you.

```
QGraphicsScene scene;   
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton; 

//Add item and obtain QGraphicsProxyWidget 
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = scene.addWidget(button);

//Remove item
scene.removeItem(proxy);
```

Just remember to delete any memory you allocate.

Edit: After OP's comments, maybe this is what you want

```
//add item
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget;
proxy = scene.addWidget(button);

//remove item
scene.removeItem(button->graphicsProxyWidget());
```

Again, remember to delete proxy, or use a smart pointer.

Comment: Thanks, Maxito.  I did notice that scene.addWidget returns a proxy widget pointer, and figured what you provided is the expected method for doing this. That's how I came use a proxy in my method to begin with.  In my actual use case, the widget pointer is a class member.  I didn't want to create another class member to point to it via a proxy, hence I used the createProxy function to avoid that.

Comment: Any idea what the warnings about top-level widgets are about?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here _proxy = proxy->createProxyForChildWidget( button );_ _button_ is not a child of a widget contained in _proxy_ , _proxy_ isn't even initialized, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'm simply trying to get a QGraphicsProxyWidget pointer from a QWidget pointer.  I didn't know how.  This function did provide that.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If I understand, then you don't want to create a QGraphicsProxyWidget as a class member? If that's so, maybe you can still create proxy in your initialization and allocate it, then access it when need it with [QWidget::graphicsProxyWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#graphicsProxyWidget)

Comment: scene.removeItem(button->graphicsProxyWidget()); Is what I needed!  I didn't know that was a QWidget function. Thanks!

Comment: When I use that, I still get the warning, "QGraphicsScene::removeItem: cannot remove 0-item", but I'll live with that...

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution figured out, but I do have some warnings appearing in the console. Here's a basic approximation of what I'm doing:

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();

// Add button
QPushButton button = new QPushButton( "Test", this );
scene->addWidget( button );

// Remove button
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy;
proxy = proxy->createProxyForChildWidget( button );
scene_->removeItem( proxy );
delete proxy;
proxy = NULL;
delete button;
button = NULL;
```

Here are the warnings I see though:

QGraphicsProxyWidget::setWidget: cannot embed widget 0x604a2c8 which is not a toplevel widget, and is not a child of an embedded widget
QGraphicsProxyWidget::createProxyForChildWidget: top-level widget not in a QGraphicsScene
QGraphicsScene::removeItem: cannot remove 0-item