# How to remove a QWidget from a QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qgraphicsscene

I am trying to accomplish the following:

(1) add a QPushButton to a QGraphicsScene with addWidget()

(2) display this QGraphicsScene with QGraphicsView

(3) remove that button later (for example, when I click it).

I have done (1) and (2) but I have no idea how to do (3). [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079899/qgraphicsscene-does-not-have-a-function-to-remove-qwidget) on this site asked a similar question, one of whose answers suggested something like the following:

```cpp
    QPushButton* startGame = new QPushButton("Start Game");
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    QGraphicsProxyWidget* proxy = scene->addWidget(startGame);

    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsView->show();

    scene->removeItem(proxy);// without this everything is fine
```

But I received this error: no matching function for call to QGraphicsScene::removeItem(QGraphicsProxyWidget*&)'. Why is this? How can I solve it?

Btw, I am using Qt creator 4.7.0 based on Qt 5.11.1 (MSVC2015, 32 bit).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `QGraphicsProxyWidget` is derived from `QGraphicsObject` which is derived from `QGraphicsItem`. Hence, it should work. If not, I assume that either you are missing an `#include` or you made a typo which is not exposed here. (Though, I tend to the former.) Please, try whether error can be eliminated with `#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>`. This might help because the previous usage `QGraphicsProxyWidget* proxy = scene->addWidget(startGame);` might have worked with an incomplete type but `scene->removeItem(proxy);` does not because it needs inheritance relation to work properly.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I didn't include this file. I didn't realize this could be a problem since  that QGraphicsProxyWidget pointer can be declared without receiving any error, and I assumed it was included in other headers.

Comment: It's probably forward declared. (I saw this often in Qt sources.) Hence, it may be used as pointer and nothing else...